# DENSE_RANK not working as expected

Tags: sql-server

I have a situation where I need to assign a unique "ID" for every unique address. Each row contains other columns as well, besides the "address" columns.

My query is:

```
SELECT umLocationID,
       arcs_name1,
       arcs_name2,
       arcs_addr1,
       arcs_addr2,
       arcs_city,
       arcs_state,
       arcs_zip,
       arcs_country,
       arcs_cust_class,
       RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY arcs_name1,
                                arcs_name2,
                                arcs_addr1,
                                arcs_addr2,
                                arcs_city,
                                arcs_state,
                                arcs_zip,
                                arcs_country 
                   ORDER BY arcs_name1,
                            arcs_name2,
                            arcs_addr1,
                            arcs_addr2,
                            arcs_city,
                            arcs_state,
                            arcs_zip,
                            arcs_country) AS 'Rank_Address#',
       DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY arcs_name1,
                                      arcs_name2,
                                      arcs_addr1,
                                      arcs_addr2,
                                      arcs_city,
                                      arcs_state,
                                      arcs_zip,
                                      arcs_country 
                         ORDER BY arcs_name1,
                                  arcs_name2,
                                  arcs_addr1,
                                  arcs_addr2,
                                  arcs_city,
                                  arcs_state,
                                  arcs_zip,
                                  arcs_country) AS 'Dense_Rank_Address#'
  FROM #Cleanout_artstcid2
```

Both my `RANK()` and `DENSE_RANK()` are giving the same result, a value of 1 for every row of the query results. What am I doing wrong? I know there is a need to use `DISTINCT` with `DENSE_RANK` but I cannot use it given the requirements for my overall query. Here is a screenshot of what I am getting (partial columns).[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove your `PARTITION` clause. The **window functions** are calculated within the `PARTITION` itself, and it sounds like you're trying to rank the data globally (i.e. uniquely rank the addresses globally).

Or adjust the `PARTITION` clause to reflect the window of what you want the rank to be calculated across. For example, if you wanted to rank the data within the field `arcs_name1` then you'd use `PARTITION arcs_name1` only (but leave your `ORDER BY` clause as is) and the ranking would only be within the grouping of each value of `arcs_name1` (resetting it's *counter* between each unique value of `arcs_name1`).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, I need to rank by that whole set of columns that appear either in the PARTITION or ORDER BY clause. **All** those columns constitute a unique _Address_ for my query. It works partially if I remove the PARTITION BY clause but the Address# keeps incrementing as new customers keep showing up. I want it to reset to 1 for each customer. The idea being I want capture all customers that 1 address (ranking them 1) and additional addresses to be ranked 2,3,4.. Without PARTITION, the rank simply keeps incrementing. I want it to reset to 1 for each unique _address_.

Comment: I think you had it spot on. I believe adjusting the PARTITION BY to just the "arcs_name1" column, which is whole point, was the answer. Thank you for pointing it out!

Comment: @Jurasick Great! No problem! Sorry sometimes I write up a quick answer to directly answer the problem and add more clarifying details after. Glad it's working for you!